# Highest Observation Carried Forward

Tags: r

I am trying to carry the highest observation forward in a vector, replacing both NAs and any value lower than the last highest observation. E.g.

```
c(1,2,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA)
```

would become

```
c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
```

What is the best way to do this in a vectorized fashion?

Comment: Vectorized? It is going to have to be iterative, I don't think this can be parallelized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA)
y <- x
y[is.na(y)] <- -Inf
y <- cummax(y)
y[y == -Inf] <- NA
#[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Comment: Excellent usage of `-Inf` and `cummax`, the third step results in desired output and no `-Inf` instances remain, any specific reason for the fourth step

Comment: @Osssan There could be `NA` values in the beginning of the vector. If you ommit that step you'd get `-Inf` values there which might not be desired.